# How to generate Api clients for Http triggered Azure functions (isolated/out-of-process)?

Tags: azure-functions, openapi-generator, nswag, autorest

I have Http triggered Azure function (Isolated), the API specification is defined using DataAnotations (`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core`). As part of Azure DevOps build process i want to generate C# REST client and publish it as artifacts. I have looked into NSwag/AutoRest examples and have not been able find suitable reference/example.  Is the tooling available to generate clients for out-of-process azure function, if so suggest/guide to proceed forward.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger UI can be used to generate the OpenAPI. Due to its reliance on the in-process model, the extension will not work now that the out-of-process model is available.

Here's how Jan Hajek came up with a solution in his [BLOG](https://hajekj.net/2021/04/24/openapi-and-azure-functions-out-of-process/) for generating OpenAPI Client for Azure functions (isolated/out-of-process).

step 1: In .NET 5.0, create a function.

step 2: Creating the model.

step 3: Assign appropriate endpoints and correctly annotate them.

REFERENCES:

1. [Quickstart: Create your first C# function in Azure using Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio?tabs=isolated-process&pivots=programming-runtime-functions-v3)
2. [A sample project showing the use of OpenAPI.NET.CSharpAnnotations with Azure Functions (github.com)](https://github.com/hajekj/azure-functions-openapi-demo)

Comment: Thanks.  I have Azure function (isolated) developed and deployed (via. Azure pipelines), the API definition is implemented using DataAnotations (using Extensions.OpenApi.Core).  I wanted to auto-generate rest clients against this DataAnotation (OpenAPI) specification as part of DevOps process, and this is where i wanted suggestion on solution.  In my search i couldn't find any reference that uses Nswag/AutoRest for Isolated implementation.

Comment: The simple fact is that isolated mode is not very good for generating API clients. You have to annote the methods yourself which in itself is bad since those annotations can become out of synk if you are not carefull. In my opinion this is not ready for real use outside of very simple use cases.